# Proving certain properties for Babylonian method

Tags: analysis

The Babylonian method for approximating square roots is divided into three steps:

1. Guess an initial approximation $a$ of $ {\sqrt N}$, where $a$ and $N$ are postive rational numebrs and $N$ is not the square of any rational numbers.
2. Let $c=\frac{N-a^2}{2a}$.
3. Now $a+c$ is a new approximation of $ {\sqrt N}$.

**The question is to show $a+c>\sqrt N$.**

I think that since the problem did not inform us of the relationship between $a$ and ${\sqrt N}$, so no matter what number we pick for $a$ does not affect the fact that $a+c>\sqrt N$.
Then we will have

$a+c=a+\frac{N-a^2}{2a}=\frac{a^2+N}{2a}$, if $a$ >$\sqrt N$, then we will have $\frac{a^2+N} {2a} >\frac{2N}{2a}$, $\frac{2N}{2a}<\frac{2N}{2\sqrt N}=\sqrt N$. However, how do I find the relation between $\frac{a^2+N} {2a}  $ and $\frac{2N}{2\sqrt N}$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
a+c &= a + \frac{N - a^2}{2a}
= \frac{N + a^2}{2a}
= \frac{(\sqrt{N} - a)^2 + 2a\sqrt{N}}{2a}\\
&=  \frac{(\sqrt{N} - a)^2}{2a} + \sqrt{N} \geq \sqrt{N}
\end{align*}

Comment: Make sense to me. Thanks!